# How to configure SMTP in IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

How to to configure SMTP mail in IIS 7?

I am new to IIS 7 and want to know how to configure that, or its better to keep using the IIS 6 SMTP?

Any one know where to find some videos to learn SMTP in IIS 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IIS7 SMTP server is managed using IIS6 management console.

Comment: and why wouldn't it be ... excellent decision #132,302,092,234 by Microsoft

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. There's an IIS6 management console component that you'd use.

Comment: Off-topic, but unless you really really really must have smtp on your own servers, I recommend using a third party smtp. They are generally far more reliable and blacklist resistant that anything you can host yourself. Let the network pros handle reverse dns, spf records, and white listing, and let the programmers program instead of wasting time debugging email woes. &lt;/rant&gt;

Comment: i find it strange that they use iis 6 management console and expect us to know where to find what. Is SMTP just a second class citizen that they will never port to IIS7?